# Undefined value passed into INSERT statement using NodeJS,Mysql,React app

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

Please find my code and error.

My App.js frontend code

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  
  const [Var_EName,setName] = useState("")
  const [Var_Age,setAge] = useState(0)
  const [Var_Country,setCountry] = useState("")
  const [Var_Position,setPosition] = useState("")
  const [Var_Sal,setSalary] = useState(0)
  //const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState([]);

  const AddEmployee = () => {

    Axios.post('http://192.168.137.1:3001/create',
    {Ename:Var_EName,
     EAge:Var_Age,
     ECountry:Var_Country,
     EPosition:Var_Position,
     ESal:Var_Sal}).then(() => 
     console.log("Succssfully Inserted") 
     )
  }
  
  const displayEmpInfo = () => {
    console.log(Var_EName  +Var_Age + Var_Country + Var_Position + Var_Sal)
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">CRUD Application Using NodeJS ReactApp MySql</header>

      <div className="empinformation">
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} ></input>
        <label>Age :</label>
        <input type="number" onChange={(event) => setAge(event.target.value)}></input>
        <label>Country :</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) => setCountry(event.target.value)}></input>
        <label>Position :</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) => setPosition(event.target.value)}></input>
        <label>Salary(Per Year) :</label>
        <input type="number" onChange={(event) => setSalary(event.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={AddEmployee}>Add Employee</button>
        <button onClick={displayEmpInfo}>Disp Emp</button>
     </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

And my index.js code for backend as below.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host:"localhost",
    password:"Kalpataru",
    database:"sakila"
});

db.connect(function (err) {
    // connection.end();
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... \n");
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... \n");
    }
});


app.post("/create",(req,res) => {
    
    console.log('Employee Name : ' + req.body.EName);
    const Var_EName = req.body.EName;
    const Var_Age = req.body.EAge;
    const Var_Country = req.body.ECountry;
    const Var_Position = req.body.EPosition;
    const Var_Sal = req.body.ESal;
    

    db.query("INSERT INTO employes(Ename,EAge,ECountry,EPosition,ESal) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
    [Var_EName,Var_Age,Var_Country,Var_Position,Var_Sal], 
    (err,result) => {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err)
        }else
        {
           res.send("Values Inserted & Saved To Database.") 
        }
    }
    );

});


app.listen(3001,() => {
    console.log("Yeah, Your Server is running on Port : 3001")
});
```

The below error i get in server terminal.

```
PS C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server> node index.js
Yeah, Your Server is running on Port : 3001
Database is connected ...

Employee Name : undefined
Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'Ename' cannot be null
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
    at C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\index.js:37:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\CRUD-APPLICATION\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {
  code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlMessage: "Column 'Ename' cannot be null",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  **sql: "INSERT INTO employes(Ename,EAge,ECountry,EPosition,ESal) VALUES(NULL,'38','India','Developer','800000')"**
}
```

sql: "INSERT INTO employes(Ename,EAge,ECountry,EPosition,ESal) VALUES(NULL,'38','India','Developer','800000')"

**As You all can see in INSERT statement other values i am getting correctly values except Ename value passing as null**

Where is the issue & how to solve the issue ?

Please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo.
In the frontend code :

```
 Axios.post('http://192.168.137.1:3001/create',
    {Ename:Var_EName, /// <--- It should be "EName:Var_EName" instead of "Ename:Var_EName"
     EAge:Var_Age,
     ECountry:Var_Country,
     EPosition:Var_Position,
     ESal:Var_Sal}).then(() => 
     console.log("Succssfully Inserted") 
     )
  }
```

In the backend :

```
 const Var_EName = req.body.EName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer , it works.
As i am new to React & NodeJS ,so don't understand which one is variable and which one is column value.

I thought that Ename is the column and Var_EName is the variable.

Is it true ?
How do we set or use or write something as a variable and database column ?

Please reply and Thanks again for your response.

Comment: It's not about which one is a variable or a column. The reason why you got `undefined` simply because of [javascript case sensitivity](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Is-JavaScript-a-case-sensitive-language). What's the difference between `Ename` and `EName` is the small and capital letter of **N**.

Comment: totally agree with @FaNo_FN. It is just a typo.